# Flattening lists (while removing 'nil' and keeping atoms after " . ") in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I want to create a function that would flatten a list and remove all potential `nil` inside.

Expected behavior, example 1:

```
(myfunc '(a (b (c) (d)) (e f) (g (h)) nil)) => (a b c d e f g h)
```

Expected behavior, example 2:

```
(myfunc '(a . d)) => (a d)
```

my function so far:

```
(defun myfunc (l)
   (cond
      ((atom l) nil)
         ((and (atom (car l)) (not (equal (car l) nil))) (cons (car l) (myfunc (cdr l))))
         (t (append (myfunc (car l)) (myfunc (cdr l))))))
```

My function works as expected for the first example, but not the second. 
I get:

```
(myfunc '(a . d)) => (a)
```

1. Why doesn't it keep that `d`?
2. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: The way to fix it is to walk through your code with the failing example line by line. It will take about two minutes, and you will start to build a feel for linked lists and cons and cdr at the same time you see how it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should think about what the flatten function *should* do, in plain English:

1. Base case: If flattening `nil`, return an empty list.
2. Base case: If flattening single atoms, return a list containing just that.
3. Recursive case: If flattening pairs, return a list appending the flattening of its `car` with the flattening of its `cdr`.

Here's how I'd implement the description I just gave:

```
(defun flatten (x)
  (cond ((null x) x)
        ((atom x) (list x))
        (t (nconc (flatten (car x)) (flatten (cdr x))))))
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you describe what nconc does? I read the doc here http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nconc.htm , but it's still not so clear to me. Thanks again!

Comment: looks like I get the same result if I replace "nconc" by "append" on the last line, right?

Comment: @RainerJoswig Thanks! Applied. (I tried looking for `atomp`, but missed `atom`, lol. As you know, Scheme doesn't have `atom?`; `(not (pair? ...))` is pretty much it.)

Comment: @JonathP `nconc` stands for non-consing concatenate. It's like `append` but by mutating the incoming lists rather than copying. In many cases, you can safely replace `nconc` with `append`; it'll just do more copying. You cannot always replace `append` with `nconc`, though; it may modify things you didn't expect. In this case, all the lists I `nconc`ed were either fresh lists generated with the `(list x)` expression (on the `(atom x)` case), or nil, so I know those are safe.

Comment: (In contrast, in Scheme, `nconc` is called `append!`, and the latter has the _option_ of doing mutation, which means the caller cannot assume mutation. So in Scheme, it's always safe to replace `append!` with `append`, and in fact, in some implementations like Racket, `append!` is defined as `append`.)

Comment: APPEND, NCONC and ATOM are from Lisp I from 1960.